# Difference between Open JDK and Oracle JDK for containerized applications

Tags: java, containers

I am looking for specific technical differences between Open JDK and Oracle JDK for containerized applications.

1. Which one will be better in terms of support for container CPU and Memory limits?
2. Overhead of GC in containerized runtime environments with varied Operating systems?
3. Which one will performant for multithreading java application deployed in container platform?

Comment: Please focus on **one** question. Dont let the upvotes trick you, as your question is written right now, it should be closed for various reasons.

Comment: Given that Oracle JDK and OpenJDK are built from essentially the same code tree, I see no reason to think that their performance is different.  Containers or no containers.  But feel free to do your own benchmarking to verify this.

Comment: @GhostCat - How this question is not focused and why do you think it should be closed for various reasons?

Comment: A) multiple questions marks indicate that you are asking more than one question, which you actually do B) and especially your last question is extremely subjective. There is a great variety of workloads, thus there is no universal "best solution" without context. C) If you did any research prior asking your question**s**, that doesn't show either. And remember: it takes 3 people to close vote a question like this.

Answer (score 2):

### Alert

Please consider about licensing terms for commercial use.

### Key Comparisons

> Oracle JDK was licensed under Oracle Binary Code License Agreement,
> whereas OpenJDK has the GNU General Public License (GNU GPL) version 2
> with a linking exception.

> There is no real technical difference between the two since the build
> process for the Oracle JDK is based on that of OpenJDK.

> If we compare features and options, we'll see that the Oracle product
> has Flight Recorder, Java Mission Control, and Application Class-Data
> Sharing features, while OpenJDK has the Font Renderer feature.

### More information

[Oracle FAQ](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk-faqs.html)

[General comparison](https://www.baeldung.com/oracle-jdk-vs-openjdk)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Cost and license are a must to consider. However, I am still not too clear on the behavior of these two JDK's in the container runtime environment. Do you have any first-hand experience with the containerized application with open and oracle jdk?

Comment: @Nikhil There is no tangible difference.to performance

Comment: @Nikhil, I have experience only with AdoptOpenJDK in kubernetes cluster(12Gi, 8cpu per container) running non-tensorflow ML inferences at 20K RPS. Did not face any JDK related issues.